# Has Michelson-Morley been repeated using modern equipment?

Tags: speed-of-light, interferometry, experimental-technology

Nowadays we have incredibly sensitive interferometers in the form of the LIGO detectors.

I am curious to know if anyone has ever repeated the Michelson-Morley experiment in the last couple of decades with an upgraded experimental setup - lasers, vibration damping, temperature compensation, and so on.

Comment: I think that the enormous number of experiments in particle physics  continually validate special relativity and there is really no reason to go into the systematics of interferometry

Comment: If there was an aether, then LIGO would not work as it does. Consider LIGO a giant Michelson-Morley experiment all by itself.

Comment: @Jon LIGO couldn't be used as the Michelson-Morley experiment because one has to rotate the arms to prove or disprove the influence of the earths movement through aether. But it would be interesting to carry out this experiment on a satellite. There is less gravitational influence from the earths matter and higher speed 90min for a rotation to the 24h).

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The Earth (a) spins and (b) moves in different directions over the course of the year. It is *exactly* the same experiment on a multi-kilometer scale.

Comment: @dmckee Think about how to they try to detect the aether. "The mercury trough allowed the device to turn with close to zero friction, so that once having given the sandstone block a single push it would slowly rotate through the entire range of possible angles to the "aether wind," while measurements were continuously observed" (wiki)[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson–Morley_experiment]. Rotating the interferometer one should (if exist) the aether wind. Instead of this rotation it would be nice to use the satellites rotation and this far away from the earth.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The interferometers at LIGO rotate *every day*. That's what happens when the Earth turns. And the fringes are continuously observed. The MM device needed to rotate through 90 degree to be *barely* sensitive to the expected effect. LIGO is orders of magnitude larger and needs perhaps 10 minutes of the Earth's rotation to be sensitive to a higher degree.

Comment: Will the LISA satellites effectively re-run the experiment in space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the recent couple of decades there have been at least several experiments which could be considered variations of the Michelson-Morley setup.
A few examples: [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0210049), [2](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401017), [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2031), [4](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0504109).

Wiki actually has even [more links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Experiments).